# Top n rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, numpy, octave

I'm trying to figure out the best way of doing this, ideally in Octave, but I'll take NumPy at a pinch.

Let's say I have an axb matrix M.  If I want the row indices of the maximum value in any given column, `[x, xi] = max(M)` will return these indices for me as a row vector.

For example, if M is:

```
1  3  5 
2  9  1
7  2  4
```

The above will return row vector `[3  2  1]` as `xi`;  A vector of the indices of each row which contains the maximum value for that column.  This is good.  I want this row vector.

But what if I want the top *n* such row vectors?

[edited to explain this better]

For the above example, the first such vector would be the above `[3, 2, 1]`, (the indices of the rows with the highest values for each given column).  The second such vector would be `[2 1 3]`, (the indices of the rows with the *second-highest* values for each column).

I could do it iteratively, but my actual matrices have many thousands of rows, so this would be quite computationally expensive.  I can't find any obvious matrix utility function to help me achieve this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "top _n_ such row vectors"? What would you get in your example for _n_ = 2?

Comment: For numpy solution to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: I've edited to explain this better in the original question.  Hopefully it now makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you mean you want the n biggest values from the matrix.  In which case, [Get the indices of the n largest elements in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692482/get-the-indices-of-the-n-largest-elements-in-a-matrix) is almost the same question as this, except there the OP wanted the largest values of the whole matrix, not individual maximums.  This should get you what you need

```
n = 2;               % The depth to get
M = [ 1, 3, 5; ...
      2, 9, 1; ...
      7, 2, 4 ];     % The matrix to look at
[m, mi] = sort(M, 'descend');  % Sort the to access them
x = m(1:n, :)        % Get the values
xi = mi(1:n, :)      % and the indices
```

Comment: This is, in retrospect, a very obvious way to do this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
% N is the number of rows you want to include.
[x, xi] = max(a(1:N,:))
```

This gives you:

```
a =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

N = 3;
[x, xi] = max(a(1:N,:))

x =    
    16    11    10    13       
xi =   
     1     2     2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in numpy. Please take a look at [`numpy.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), which returns indices of the maximum values along an axis. Note that this indices are 0-based so you may want to add/subtract 1 to it to make it 1-based as in matlab.

Taking the same example of @Stewie Griffin :-)

```
In [3]: a = np.array([[16,2,3,13], [5,11,10,8], [9,7,6,12], [4,14,15,1]])

In [4]: N = 2 # A 0-based index 

In [5]: np.argmax(a[N], axis=0)
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Here the axis is 0 because you want max indices in each column. Change it to 1 if you want max indices in each raw. Also, there is [`numpy.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) if you want min.

---

Based on your clarification,you want nth largest indices in each column, which is very easy with [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort).

```
In [11]: A = np.argsort(a, axis=0) # returns indices of smallest to largest values in each column

In [12]: A
Out[12]: 
array([[3, 0, 0, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 3, 0]])

In [13]: N = 1 # 0-based index

In [14]: A[N] # 2nd smallest indices
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 2, 1])

In [14]: A[-N-1] # 2nd largest indices
Out[14]: array([2, 1, 1, 2])
```