# How to find indexes of k maximal values in a given NxN (symetric) matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix which state (in each enterence (i,j)) the correlations of the (i,j) pair.
I want the indexes of k pairs with maximal correlations.
Any ideas?
My matrix could get big so I am looking for the matlabs elegant array/matrix commands
(if there is any)

Thanks!

**remark**: If this is not the right place for this question, I would be thankfull to get a link to another forum or an answer to a similar question in this forum

Comment: try looking here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692482/get-the-indices-of-the-n-largest-elements-in-a-matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692482/get-the-indices-of-the-n-largest-elements-in-a-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function [values,i,j] = maxi(A,n)
[a, linIdx] = sort(A(:),'descend');
values = a(1:n);
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(A),linIdx(1:n));
```

where input *A* is a matrix, and *n* is the number of *(i,j)* pairs you want returned. Outputs are of course the *n* maximum values and their corresponding indices.

I hope this helps.

Note: If *A* contains a lot of zero elements, consider using sparse matrix to decrease computation time.

Comment: @user135172 : Note that I improved the sloppy code I submitted before. This will be faster, and the code looks much better. Enjoy ;)